# Saving an Image as an OIB File in Python

Tags: python, image, save

I want to save an image/an array as an OIB File.

I have tried using the oiffile library. I am able to open and read OIB files, but I want to save an image as an OIB File.

Answer (score 0):

Since `oiffile` uses `cv2` structure for opening/closing images (via `numpy` arrays), so you might be opening the image using `imread()`. Then you can use `imwrite()` for saving/writing the image file to a destination path.